# ListPlot doesn't start from the origin

Tags: plotting

I've just started using Mathematica for one my university modules, so I tried replicating the results from our practical.

I've defined a function

```
f[x_]:= ax - R/2 x^2
```

After this, if I define

```
ListA = Table [f[j/5] /.a -> 5 /.R -> 1/4,{j,0,75}]
```

And then plot it with `Plot1 = ListPlot[ListA]` my graph will start from 1, rather than 0 (screenshot below)
[image]

However, if I define

```
ListB = Table [f{j/5},f[j/5] /.a -> 5 /.R -> 1/4,{j,0,75}]
```

And then plot it with `Plot2 = ListPlot[ListB]`, the graph starts from 0, as seen below
[image]

Can anyone explain to me the logic in these commands? I've tried searching for the answer both on StackExchange and in Google and couldn't find anything. I really appreciate it!

P.S. Is there any way to manually adjust the colour-coding of syntax? I've figured out that it changes to green/orange when I stop typing, but some colour-coding is different from the original code, so I am not sure what to do with it. This is my first time posting on StackExchange, so I am still figuring it out

Comment: In definition of "f" you use "ax", but in "ListA" and "ListB" you use "a". Then, the definition of "ListB" is wrong syntax. Table take 2 arguments not 3

Comment: Welcome to the community. Take a look at [`DiscretePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html). Side note, you can replace multiple items simultaneously like `/. {a -> 5, R -> 1/4}`

Comment: @DanielHuber I think I made a mistake of not put a space between 'a' and 'x'. I just want to define a function with a constant 'a' and a variable 'x'

Comment: There's something funny with your code, but... It is a common convention in Mathematica that if a list of numeric values (instead of lists for multi-dimensional data) is given as input to a function which expects multi-dimensional data, it is interpreted as `{{1, val1}, {2, val2}, ...}` by default, starting "x coordinate" from 1. In the case of `ListPlot` this fact is implied by the documentation definition of the first syntax form, where you can see $\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$ being interpreted as $\{\{i,y_i\},\ldots,\{n,y_n\}\}$ which corresponds with $\{\{1,y_1\}\},\ldots,\{n,y_n\}\}$.

Answer (score -1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] := **a x** - R/2 x^2 ;

ListA = Table[f[j/5] /. a -> 5 /. R -> 1/4, {j, 0, 75}]

Plot1 = ListPlot[ListA]

ListB = Table[f {j/5}, f[j/5] /. a -> 5 /. R -> 1/4, {j, 0, 75}]
```

Comment: This does not evaluate as posted. Please check for correctness and repost. Thanks.